# Policy Injection ExceptionCallHandler doesn't fire handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception, unity-container, policy

I have configured my unity dependency this way:

```
<register type="IFeedController" mapTo="RaF.Controllers.FeedController, Raf">
    <interceptor type="VirtualMethodInterceptor"></interceptor>
    <interceptionBehavior type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.PolicyInjectionBehavior, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception" />
</register>
```

I have setup the exception manager this way:

```
public class ApplicationExceptionManager : IApplicationExceptionManager
{
    private Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionManager _exceptionManager;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets EntLibs Exception Manager instance
    /// </summary>
    public ExceptionManager ExceptionManager
    {
        get { return _exceptionManager; }
    }
    public ApplicationExceptionManager()
    {
        var exceptionHandlingPolicies = new List<ExceptionPolicyDefinition>();
        var azureExceptionPolicies = ExceptionPolicies.AzureExceptionPolicies;
        var systemExceptionPolicies = ExceptionPolicies.SystemExceptionPolicies;
        var webAppExceptionPolicies = ExceptionPolicies.WebAppExceptionPolicies;
        exceptionHandlingPolicies.Add(new ExceptionPolicyDefinition(ExceptionPolicies.AzureExceptionPolicy, azureExceptionPolicies));
        exceptionHandlingPolicies.Add(new ExceptionPolicyDefinition(ExceptionPolicies.SystemExceptionPolicy, systemExceptionPolicies));
        exceptionHandlingPolicies.Add(new ExceptionPolicyDefinition(ExceptionPolicies.WebAppExceptionPolicy, webAppExceptionPolicies));

        _exceptionManager = new Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionManager(exceptionHandlingPolicies);
    }
    Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionManager IApplicationExceptionManager.ExceptionManager
    {
        get { return _exceptionManager; }
    }
}
```

Then I set the exception manager using:

```
ExceptionManager manager = new ApplicationExceptionManager().ExceptionManager;
ExceptionPolicy.SetExceptionManager(manager, true);
```

Which would then allow me to use the `ExceptionCallHandlerAttribute` on my controller and dependencies.

Unfortunately, the handlers declared are never firing and I'm lost at where things went awry. It's a simple ASP.NET MVC WebApi controller project with Unity as Dependency Resolver.

What next should I check? Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net MVC and WebAPI controllers don't use interfaces or virtual methods for they actions - so Unity interceptors can't intercept such action calls.

If you need to use corresponding Action Filters to handle exception and other cross-cutting concerns. You may also set such filter as global filter.

Note: make sure to pick correct filters - all related classes look very similar and it is easy to misuse MVC attribute for WebAPI controller.

Answer (score 0):

By default UnityConfig.cs is not configured with the interception extension. Below is the adjustment done:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
RegisterTypes(container);
return container;
```

The add new extension is required. Unity doesn't fire an exception if an interception behavior is declared on a dependency but the container doesn't have the extension added. It's now working properly. Also, the interception does work properly on ApiController and Controller although it might be appropriate to use Filters.